# Observable array is empty in ngrx

Tags: arrays, angular, rxjs, ngrx-store

I have a an observable array that binds to a data grid in the html and this is working fine. My component.ts gets the array like:

```
this.data = this.store.pipe(select(selectData));
```

where `selectData` is an ngrx action. I'm trying to set the value of an `input` outside the data grid based on the first value in the data array. I'm trying something like

```
this.input= this.data.pipe(map(m => 
      moment(new Date(m[0].timestamp / 1000000)).format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss')));
```

When I'm debugging this, I can see the break point on the line with `moment(new Date...` hitting. However, the `m` at this time is an empty array. Both of the above statements are declared in `ngOnInit` like

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.data = this.store.pipe(select(selectData));
    this.input= this.data.pipe(map(m => 
      moment(new Date(m[0].timestamp / 1000000)).format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss')));
  }
```

It looks like the observable is resolved before the array is actually populated causing the `input` to be `undefined`. How can I make sure that the `this.data` array is actually fully populated by the time I try to set the `this.input`?

Comment: `this.store.select(selectData).pipe(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to subscribe in order for the selector to pick up data from the store. Make the following change:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
   this.store.pipe(select(selectData))
      .subscribe(m => {
         this.input = moment(new Date(m[0].timestamp / 1000000))
                          .format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss');
      });
}
```